# How to get exact file size and file name?

Tags: command-line, shell-script, ls

Right now I am using `ls -lt /my/directory` (see below) then php parses the output. But inconsistently because the delimiter is space and there might be two or more spaces in between two fields.

The solution is output only **file name** and **its size**. How can I list files (using wild card) and its full size in command line?

So instead of

```
-rw------- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 855658496 Apr 22 02:31 MONTE.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20120422023005.001
```

I get

```
855658496 MONTE.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20120422023005.001
```

Comment: [Don't parse `ls` output, **ever**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  Instead, you should be asking how to get the information you want directly with PHP in a more robust fashion, perhaps on StackOverflow?

Comment: I do ls on remote server over ssh so I cannot do it directly in PHP.

Comment: If you can, mount the remote directory over [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) and forget about parsing `ls` or `stat` output.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As others have noted, if this is a dynamic web application, you're much better off using PHP's functions for accessing file size.

But if you're going to get it by executing a shell command, don't use `ls`. Instead, use [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat), and tell it exactly what you want:

```
$ stat -c '%n %s' x.txt
x.txt 12
```

Comment: The `-t` used in the original `ls` call can hardly be reproduced this way.

Comment: The full command I am going to use is `ssh root@monte stat -c \'%n %s\' /var/lib/edumate/backup/*MONTE*` . Thank you.

Comment: @manatwor: thank you for pointing that out. Need to so some sorting in php then.

Comment: @Radek, then you would probably like to add `%Y` (time of last modification, seconds since Epoch) too to the format string.

Comment: The file name contains timestamp so I can use that. Thank for the comment. I would need that if no timestamp.

Comment: @Radek Beware that if file names can contain newlines, you will not be able to parse the output.

Comment: It's already working nicely :-)

Comment: On OS X (and probably other BSDs) stat takes different options. The equivalent to the command in the answer would be: `stat -f '%N %z' x.txt`.